# Moving data from one table to another while also creating entries when no corresponding row exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two tables `CourtCase` and `CaseResult`. `CaseResult` contains the foreign key `CourtCaseID` which refers to the `CourtCase` table.

The table `CourtCase` contains a field `CompleteDate`. I would like to migrate `CompleteDate` from the `CourtCase` table to the `CaseResult` table.

The query I have come up with to migrate the data:

```
UPDATE CaseResult 
SET CaseResult.CompleteDate = CourtCase.CompleteDate 
FROM CourtCase, CaseResult 
WHERE CourtCase.CourtCaseID = CaseResult.CourtCaseID
```

The issue is that not every `CourtCase` has an entry in `CaseResult`, only some do. So i would need to move over the dates for cases that exist with a query like the above, but also create the entries in `CaseResult` for the cases that don't exist, and insert the foreign key `CourtCaseID` and `CompleteDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps, first you update the existing records, and second you create the new records. I also encourage you to use proper JOINs.

```
UPDATE CaseResult 
SET CaseResult.CompleteDate = CourtCase.CompleteDate 
FROM CourtCase
     INNER JOIN CaseResult ON CourtCase.CourtCaseID = CaseResult.CourtCaseID

INSERT INTO CaseResult (CourtCaseID, CompleteDate)
       SELECT CourtCaseID, CompleteDate 
       FROM CourtCase
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CaseResult WHERE CaseResult.CourtCaseID = CourtCase.CourtCaseID)
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can do this in a single statement, using [the `MERGE` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which implements the "update or insert" logic, also called *upsert*:

```
merge CaseResults cr
    using CourtCase cc
    on (cr.CourtCaseID = cc.CourtCaseID)
when matched then update set 
    cr.CompleteDate = cc.CompleteDate
when not matched by target then insert (CourtCaseID, CompleteDate)
    values(cc.CourtCaseID, cc.CompleteDate)
```

You did not tell all columns that are available in the table. This assumes just two colums, `CourtCaseID` and `CompleteDate`. You might need to adjust the `insert` part with more columns, according to your actual schema.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use MERGE in order to accomplish your goal: That allows you to define what you want to do for each row found in CourtCase that you want to be represented in CaseResult.
A rough example:

```
MERGE CaseResult AS r
USING CourtCase AS c
ON (r.CourtCaseID = c.CourtCaseID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY CaseResult
   THEN INSERT (CourtCaseID, CompleteDate) VALUES (c.CourtCaseID, c.CompleteDate)
WHEN MATCHED
   THEN UPDATE SET r.CompleteDate = c.CompleteDate
;
```

See MERGE under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/bb522522(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/bb510625%28v%3dsql.100%29 for detailed information.

(*removed earlier MySQL answer*)

Comment: Can you point to the documentation for `on duplicate key update` in `tsql`? I think that's a `mysql` feature.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to tsql. I failed to recognize the specific sql-dialect, earlier. I adjusted the answer to the best of my knowledge.